# Uber Api returns 401 on php localhost

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, uber-api

i have a problem over here, i simply can't get uber to return anything else than

I have activated all scopes in the app created on Uber Dashboard(even the limited access ones), and allowed access to the app, via POSTMAN

```
{"code":"unauthorized","message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided."}
```

Redirect URI is to my localhost where i use the folowing code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/me"); //v2 does not work for some reason
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/me"); //i used this aswel, same thing happens
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$_GET['code'];       #$_GET['code'] has been replaced by my oauth2 token

$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en_US";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "<li>".$httpcode;
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

This is the response i get from the code above:

```
Array
(
[0] => Authorization: Bearer auth-token-from-get //please let me know if i made the header correctly
[1] => Accept-Language: en_US
[2] => Content-Type: application/json
)
401

{"code":"unauthorized","message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided."}
```

Can please anybody give me a hint here? i looked all over the place for a solution and it is really hard to find

Comment: Did you in a first time do the 2 other step before getting the OAuth 2.0 credential for a bearer ? because it looks like it's not the same as the primary one

Comment: do you mean 
1)User authorizes your app - done
2)Receive Redirect -done
?

Comment: I mean Authorize a rider for your application step 1 - 2 - 3, because bearer in your authorization token type is for a bearer apparently. maybe you could try to change `bearer` to `token` or i'm just wrong and i don't know how to help you

Comment: if i curl on this link 
https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=37.7752315&longitude=-122.418075
with token = server token, it will return information, but this does not require the OAUTH2 token

Comment: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/curl It's just i read this

Comment: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/user-access-token this is what i need to use actually

Comment: When you try the Quickstart does it work ? It's before the first step

Comment: yes, that works, when i access it the first time, Uber asks for permission for the specific app, and i can allow access, but after that the app will not work with any request, i either get {"error":"invalid_grant"} or {"error":"invalid_request"}